# Why does Spark job fail with "too many open files"?

Tags: apache-spark

I get "too many open files" during the shuffle phase of my Spark job.  Why is my job opening so many files? What steps can I take to try to make my job succeed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[This has been answered on the spark user list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/quot-Too-many-open-files-quot-exception-on-reduceByKey-td2462.html):

> The best way is definitely just to increase the ulimit if possible, 
>   this is sort of an assumption we make in Spark that clusters will be 
>   able to move it around.
>
> You might be able to hack around this by decreasing the number of 
>   reducers [or cores used by each node] but this could have some performance implications for your 
>   job.
>
> In general if a node in your cluster has C assigned cores and you run 
>   a job with X reducers then Spark will open C*X files in parallel and 
>   start writing. Shuffle consolidation will help decrease the total 
>   number of files created but the number of file handles open at any 
>   time doesn't change so it won't help the ulimit problem.
>
> -Patrick Wendell

Comment: I thought one of the primary benefits of spark was it keeps things in ram.. why would it have to open so many files then?

Comment: It uses those files during shuffle. The idea is to first stage the data for each reducer on local disk, then the reducer can consume data on its own pace (pull instead of push).

Comment: just in case someone else steps into the same issue using mesos, quoting the same spark user list thread:
"It turns out the mesos can overwrite the OS ulimit -n setting. So we have increased the mesos slave ulimit -n setting."

Answer (score 15):

the default ulimit is 1024 which is ridiculously low for large scale applications.  HBase recommends up to 64K; modern linux systems don't seem to have trouble with this many open files.

use

```
ulimit -a
```

to see your current maximum number of open files

```
ulimit -n
```

can temporarily change the number of open files; you need to update the system configuration files and per-user limits to make this permanent.  On CentOS and RedHat systems, that can be found in

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
/etc/security/limits.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for this error is reducing your partitions.

check to see if you've got a lot of partitions with:

```
someBigSDF.rdd.getNumPartitions()

Out[]: 200

#if you need to persist the repartition, do it like this
someBigSDF = someBigSDF.repartition(20)

#if you just need it for one transformation/action, 
#you can do the repartition inline like this
someBigSDF.repartition(20).groupBy("SomeDt").agg(count("SomeQty")).orderBy("SomeDt").show()
```