# Spark fails with too many open files on HDInsight YARN cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight

I am running into the same issue as in this thread with my Scala Spark Streaming application: [Why does Spark job fail with "too many open files"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707629/why-does-spark-job-fail-with-too-many-open-files)

But given that I am using Azure HDInsights to deploy my YARN cluster, and I don't think I can log into that machine and update the ulimit in all machines.

Is there any other way to solve this problem? I cannot reduce the number of reducers by too much either, or my job will become much slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh into all nodes from the head node (ambari ui show fqdn of all nodes).

```
ssh sshuser@nameofthecluster.azurehdinsight.net
```

You can the write a [custom action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster-linux) that alters the settings on the necessary nodes if you want to automate this action.