# Too many open files (IOException) eventhough i'm only opening a single file

Tags: java, spark-java

I am having a trouble in my program. my java program which acts as a web service(built on spark framework) is throwing an IOException called 'Too many open files' even though am only accessing a single file in my application and using try-with-resource which will eventually close the file.. this is a bit of code where am accessing a file:

```
    public synchronized JSONObject read() {
    if (jsonObject == null) {
        LOGGER.info("Reading a json file");
        String line = "";
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("..path../sample.json");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

here, jsonObject is an instance variable of course. when i run this application and hit something through postman, its only calling the 'if' block once even though every request require a data from the sample.json file(so, this was really what i expected, i.e., should read the file only once).. but after a while my server where this application was deployed gets crashed with the above mentioned IOException. i tried lot of surfing, still no luck finding the solution.

## EDITED:

This is the stack trace:

```
  [qtp1477164349-12-acceptor-0@5ef8508f-ServerConnector@503fa520{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4567}] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector -
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.accept(ServerConnector.java:379)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:638)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: where is the exception thrown?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace as well

Comment: The cause of the problem is somewhere else.  Some other part of your codebase is leaking resources.

Comment: @Lino i have edited the post with the stack trace.

Comment: @StephenC, which is odd because i don't have any other resources operation in the entire project

Comment: @RobAu, posted, the idea here is to read a file(which doesn't reside inside the JAR) only once(for the first request), and then for the consequent request, it should take the file contents from the jsonObject. couldn't really achieve it with this exception being thrown, but if i include the json file inside the JAR, i get no such kind of an exception. but i can't do it this way since the json contains user's data, etc

Comment: Perhaps it's this Spark (config?) issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707629/why-does-spark-job-fail-with-too-many-open-files

Comment: @FaisalKhan - Not odd at all.  You just posted a stack trace that clearly shows that you are using a different resource: a socket.