# Change ulmit value in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, ulimit

I am running Spark codes in EC2 instance. I am running into the "Too many open files" issue (logs below), and I searched online and seems I need to set ulimit to a higher number. Since I am running the Spark job in AWS, and I don't know where the config file is, how can I pass that value in my Spark code?

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 255 in stage 19.1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 255.3 in stage 19.1 (TID 749786, 172.31.20.34, executor 207): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /media/ebs0/yarn/local/usercache/data-platform/appcache/application_1559339304634_2088/blockmgr-90a63e4a-dace-4246-a158-270b0b34c1f9/20/broadcast_13 (Too many open files)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707629/why-does-spark-job-fail-with-too-many-open-files)

Comment: The ulimit is a property of the system and user.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/how-can-i-increase-open-files-limit-for-all-processes should show you how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from changing the ulimit you should also look for connection leakages. For eg: Check if your i/o connections are properly closed. We saw `Too many open files` exception even with 655k ulimit on every node. Later we found the connection leakages in the code.