# How to change Linux system configuration of AWS EMR in Spark codes?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have an "Open too many files" error in my Spark job, and online search points to set the "ulimit" to a higher value. But "ulimit" is a Linux OS level parameter, and not a Spark configuration parameter. So I wonder how I can pass that through Spark code.

Some related posts are: [Why does Spark job fail with "too many open files"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707629/why-does-spark-job-fail-with-too-many-open-files)

Answer (score 0):

Change the linux configuration on all nodes using a bootstrap script when the EMR is created.